# SQL - partition within a comparable set

Tags: sql, sql-server

Within this table @t:

```
s   e   Status
4   5   Available
6   7   Available
8   9   WL
10  11  Available
12  14  Available
```

I'd like to return a data set like:

```
s   e   Status
4   7   Available
8   9   WL
10  14  Available
```

basically group my status column into continuous sets knowing that the data is ordered by `s` and each subsequent row, the `s` value will be one more than the previous `e` value.

I'm thinking I need to Partition the data, with a query like this:

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by status, s order by s, e, status) As Row_number, *
from @t
order by s
```

but the results don't partition correctly.

What's the correct syntax?

Comment: The use of `from @t` suggests SQL Server, so I added the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a gaps and islands problem.  If there are no gaps in the timeframes, you can use the difference of row numbers:

```
select status, min(s) as s, max(e) as e
from (select t.*, 
             row_number() over (order by s) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by status order by s) as seqnum_s
      from @t t
     ) t
group by status, (seqnum - seqnum_s)
order by min(s);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c67044582363a251b100b922505c3c07) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: the result of what your comment gives me incorrect results.. Available 4 14
WL 8 9.. I want Available 4 7, WL 8 9, Available 10 14

Comment: @duckmike . . . Fixed the error and added a db<>fiddle.